# How to run docker inside android chroot

Tags: debian, docker, chroot, android, arm

I have debian stretch installed in arm64 android phone in chrooted environment. I have installed docker-ce following these steps from [here](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/debian/#install-docker-ce).

On starting docker :: `systemctl start docker`

returns this error :: `Running in chroot, ignoring request.`

Checking using `service docker status` shows  `[FAIL] Docker is not running ... failed!`

How can I run it inside chroot on my android phone ?

Comment: Interesting: You may need real root privileges to run it. `docker` uses `chroot` (something like it), namespaces, cgroups, capabilities, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting the daemon manually with `dockerd` (rather than using systemctl).